# How to use Views with Fields Collection and filter on where used

Tags: views, entities

I am using Entity Registrations to handle registrations for a sponsored walk. I have setup a fields collection so that registrants can register more than one person at a time.

At the moment there is only one Registration Entity for the 2013 sponsored walk, but in future there will be more.

So.... In views I want to create a table that allows the admin to view the fields collection related to a specific Entity Registration. i.e. Show only those users registered for the Spring 2013 sponsored  walk or just those registered for the Summer 2013 Walk.

I could duplicate my fields collection to make a new one for each Entity Registration, but I would rather avoid that type of duplication if I can help it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are creating a view of the type Registration in that case you can add a contextual filter of the type **Registration: Host entity ID**

Now when you add the nid of the main node you would see the registration specific to that node.

Note : To get the **Registration: Host entity ID** as a contextual filter you need to enable the Registration Views module.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I dont get any Contextual filters for Host entity ID. I only get the following

Registration type: Internal, numeric registration type ID, 
Registration type: Label, 
Registration type: Locked, 
Registration type: Machine-readable name, 
Registration type: Module, 
Registration type: Status, 
Registration type: Weight

I must be doing something wrong. Any ideas what ?

Comment: what type of view are you creating? is it content view or a registration view?

Comment: and have you enabled the registrations view module?